# Change author permalink to external URL

Tags: plugin-development, author

There are several questions here on wordpress.SE that explain how you can **change the author slug** in the author permalink URL, e.g. from `http://your.blog.tld/author/author_slug/` to `http://your.blog.tld/author/whatever-you-want-it-to-be/`.

But I do not want to change the author slug. I want to:

### Change the whole author permalink to point to an external site

For example, I might have a blog at `http://my.blog.tld/`, of which I am the only author, and I want my author name under my posts to link to `http://www.my-site.tld`.

How can I implement this?

I would prefer to do this as a plugin, that is, without changing any other files, but if that is not possible I will edit whichever file is necessary.

I know that there is the [Google+ Author Information in Search Results](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-author-information-in-search-results-wordpress-plugin/) plugin, but this is a bit more complex than I know how to adapt, and out of the box it does not work with my latest WP installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the author link via the `author_link` filter:

```
function wpd_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename ){
    return 'http://my.blog.tld/';
}
add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpd_author_link', 20, 3 );
```

`$author_id` and `$author_nicename` are available to the filter so you can fetch whatever data you need to generate the correct link.